# Compare to workbooks different folder and different cell

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm new on excel vba coding.
What I try to do is compare two different csv workbooks that are in two different folder and also compare the columns in the sheets (that have diffent position)
I need also compare more than one couple of csv file.

To explain:

1. FolderA contain 123 csv file each csv file have a sheet with two column (A and B)
2. FolderB contain 123 csv file each csv file have a sheet with three column (A,B,C)

So what i search to do is compare cvs file contain in FolderA to cvs file contain in FolderB. 
But also check if column A and B contained in csv file in FolderA are equal or different to column A and C contained in csv file in FolderB
And then create a report to show the difference between the columns compared.

So for example

```
FolderA                   FolderB
WoorbookA                 WoorbookA
ColumnA   ColunmB         ColumnA   ColunmB     ColunmC
fff       123             fff       ita         123    
ddd       897             ddd       eng         897 
ccc       345             ccc       fr          345
```

report new workbook with 2 columns to mark the difference

Code I try to use below.
It lacks some instruction I know but i haven't find out nothing refer to

```
        Sub CompareWorkBooksNew()

    Const File_LocationA = "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Crusader Kings II\localisation\"
    Const File_LocationB = "D:\_GAMES\_TRADUZIONI\Traduzione CKII\Trad. Ita 3.3.2 OXYG\Trad. Ita Ck2 3.3.2\localisation\"

    Dim wbkA As Workbook, wbkB As Workbook
    Dim SheetA As Worksheet, SheetB As Worksheet
    Dim File_NameA As String, File_NameB As String
    Dim count As Integer, i As Long
    Dim arA As Variant, arB As Variant

    File_NameA = Dir(File_LocationA & "*.csv")

     ' report workbook
    Dim wbReport As Workbook, iRow As Long
    Set wbReport = Workbooks.Add()
    wbReport.Sheets(1).Range("A1:F1") = Array("File", "Row", "A", "B", "A new", "C new")
    iRow = 2

    Do While File_NameA <> ""
         File_NameB = "traduzione_" & File_NameA
        'Debug.Print File_NameA, File_NameB

        'Get the worksheets from the workbooks
        Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(File_LocationA & File_NameA, , True)
        Set SheetA = wbkA.Worksheets(1)
        arA = wbkA.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Value2
        wbkA.Close False

        Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(File_LocationB & File_NameB, , True)
        Set SheetB = wbkB.Worksheets(1)
        SheetB.Columns(2).Delete
        arB = wbkB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Value2
        wbkB.Close False
        'Debug.Print UBound(arA), UBound(arA, 2), UBound(arB), UBound(arB, 2)

        ' check equal size
        If UBound(arA) <> UBound(arB) Then
            MsgBox "Rows in A = " & UBound(arA) & vbCr & _
                   "Rows in B = " & UBound(arB), vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' compare arrays
        For i = LBound(arA) To UBound(arA)
            If arA(i, 1) <> arB(i, 1) Or arA(i, 2) <> arB(i, 2) Then

                ' report here
                With wbReport.Sheets(1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 1) = File_NameA
                    .Cells(iRow, 2) = i
                    .Cells(iRow, 3) = arA(i, 1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 4) = arA(i, 2)
                    .Cells(iRow, 5) = arB(i, 1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 6) = arB(i, 2)
                End With
                iRow = iRow + 1

                'Debug.Print arA(i, 1), arA(i, 2), arB(i, 1), arB(i, 2)

            End If
        Next

        File_NameA = Dir() ' get next file
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    wbReport.SaveAs ("D:\_GAMES\_TRADUZIONI\Traduzione CKII\Controllo Versioni2.xlsx")
    wbReport.Close False
    MsgBox count & " files compared in " & File_LocationA, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Thanks to all that could help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Now that you have posted your code, please also explain what is wrong with the code? Where did you get errors and which? Where exactly in the code did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you  want to compare the same row in both files ie A1,B1 = A1,C!, A2,B2 = A2,C2 etc ? How big approximately are the files, megabytes  ?.Do the 2 files have the same name, if not how are they connected ? Are there any other files in the folders that don't need comparing ? Are there files in one  folder than are not it the other ?

Comment: The file have not exactly the same name one is the original and one is the modified one. 
The original have more columns butI'm interested in only A and B columns.
The new one is identical to the old one except the fact that the B original column is modeved to C.
So A=A, B=C.
Are there any other files in the folders that don't need comparing ? Yes one folder that contain the same file in both version (not csv and not to be compared)
Are there files in one folder than are not it the other ? Only one.
How big approximately are the files, megabytes ? the bigger one is around 3.900 kb

Comment: If for example the original workbook filename is abc123.xlsx what would be the filename of the corresponding modified file ?

Comment: abc123.xlsx = new_abc123.xlsx

Comment: @staibuz see my update. Your locale setting for decimal separator is comma so the csv files are semicolon delimited rather than comma which I thought they were.. Adding local:=True to workbooks.open should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes reported in new workbook Report.xlsx

update - `local:=True` added to `Workbooks.Open()` to use semicolon instead of comma in CSV.

```vb
Sub CompareWorkBooks()

    Const File_LocationA = "D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Crusader Kings II\localisation\"
    Const File_LocationB = "D:\_GAMES\_TRADUZIONI\Traduzione CKII\Trad. Ita 3.3.2 OXYG\BoPItalia Trad. Ita Ck2 3.3.2\localisation\"

    Dim wbkA As Workbook, wbkB As Workbook
    Dim SheetA As Worksheet, SheetB As Worksheet
    Dim File_NameA As String, File_NameB As String
    Dim count As Integer, i As Long
    Dim arA As Variant, arB As Variant

    File_NameA = Dir(File_LocationA & "*.csv")

     ' report workbook
    Dim wbReport As Workbook, iRow As Long
    Set wbReport = Workbooks.Add()
    wbReport.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1") = Array("File", "#Code", "ENGLISH", "#CODE", "ITALIAN", "ENGLISH", _
                                               "A=A", "B=C")
    iRow = 2

    Do While File_NameA <> ""
        File_NameB = "new_" & File_NameA
        Debug.Print File_NameA, File_NameB

        'Get the worksheets from the workbooks
        Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(File_LocationA & File_NameA, ReadOnly:=True, local:=True)

        Set SheetA = wbkA.Worksheets(1)
        arA = wbkA.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A:B").Value2
        wbkA.Close False

        Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(File_LocationB & File_NameB, ReadOnly:=True, local:=True)

        Set SheetB = wbkB.Worksheets(1)
        'SheetB.Columns(2).Delete
        arB = wbkB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A:C").Value2
        wbkB.Close False
        'Debug.Print UBound(arA), UBound(arA, 2), UBound(arB), UBound(arB, 2)

        ' check equal size
        If UBound(arA) <> UBound(arB) Then
            MsgBox "Rows in A = " & UBound(arA) & vbCr & _
                   "Rows in B = " & UBound(arB), vbCritical, "Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' compare arrays
        For i = LBound(arA) To UBound(arA)
            'If arA(i, 1) <> arB(i, 1) Or arA(i, 2) <> arB(i, 3) Then

                ' report here
                With wbReport.Sheets(1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 1) = File_NameA
                    .Cells(iRow, 2) = arA(i, 1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 3) = arA(i, 2)
                    .Cells(iRow, 4) = arB(i, 1)
                    .Cells(iRow, 5) = arB(i, 2)
                    .Cells(iRow, 6) = arB(i, 3)
                    .Cells(iRow, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=RC[-3],True,False)"
                    .Cells(iRow, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=RC[-2],True,False)"

                End With
                iRow = iRow + 1

                'Debug.Print arA(i, 1), arA(i, 2), arB(i, 1), arB(i, 2)

            'End If
        Next

        File_NameA = Dir() ' get next file
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    wbReport.SaveAs ("Report.xlsx")
    wbReport.Close False
    MsgBox count & " files compared in " & File_LocationA, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much i really appreciate your effort..
I try to launch your code but it give me the following error... "0 file compared in c:\tmp\SO\Test1".
Maybe i need to open, before launching the code, the two workbooks?

Comment: @staibuz You need to put your folders in place of my test ones, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Just last question where I find out the report file?

Comment: As I said in my answer - "You need to add the reporting."

Comment: sorry as I said I'm a newbie on vba coding...
I suppose I have to modify this line <code>MsgBox count & " files compared in  & File_LocationA, vbInformation<code> in something like this: <code>MsgBox count & " files compared in "D:\_GAMES\_TRADUZIONI\Traduzione CKII\Controllo Versione + macro.csv" & File_LocationA, vbInformation<code>
Where _italic_Controllo Versione + macro.csv_italic_ is the file wehre I want to put the report

Comment: @staibuz see updated code for a basic report that you can build on.

Comment: I see thank you but I guess there is an error in the code:1) when I debug I see more than only two file compared each other 2) at the end of the process it give an error Row in A: 3124 Row in B 19. 
19  row is correct for the frist two file comparison (the old and the new).
3124 maybe is the sum of more than a file?
In fact the frist couple of file is composed : 
File old column A (19 row) column B (19 row)
File new column A (19 row) column C (19 row)
Obviously the other couple of file are composed in the same way but with different length of the row.
I hope I'm explained it well

Comment: @Staibuz Yes you are correct the line File_NameB = "new_" & File_NameA should be inside the loop - see my update

Comment: @CPD1802  see my code update in the frist post.
The report file work but not in the way as I expect.
{Report Actual WoorbookA                 WoorbookA
ColumnA   ColunmB         ColumnA   ColunmB     ColunmC
fff       123             fff       ita         123    
ddd       897             ddd       eng         897 
ccc       345             ccc       fr          345}

Comment: @Staibuz You want to see Column B _new in the report, is that the only thing wrong ?

Comment: The report file work but not in the way as I expect.
What I'm try to do is something like:

Comment: Column A   :   File's name 
Column B   :    Text of Column A (old file) only the one before the frist separator ";" 
Column B   :    Text of Column B (old file) only the one between the frist and the secon separator the separator ";" 
Column C:    Text of Column A (new file) only the one before the frist separator ";" 
Column D   :    Text of Column B (new file) only the one between the frist and the secon separator the separator ";"
Column E : the COUNT.IF fuction (=IF(A1=C1;True;False)
Column F : the COUNT.IF fuction (=IF(B1=D1;True;False)

Comment: I would like to post a screenshoot of the above mentioned but I don't know if is allowed here.

Comment: see here I think it explain all
[link]https://hosting.photobucket.com/images/ah217/staibuz/Immagine.jpg?width=1920&height=1080&fit=bounds[link]

Comment: I made the change you have suggest but now this is the result: [link]https://hosting.photobucket.com/images/ah217/staibuz/Immagine1.png

Comment: @CPD1802 could you help me again to achive the result I'm expecting to?